# JavaScript How to update the value of IMask element

Tags: javascript, html, imaskjs

I'm trying to make my `IMask` input update its value to be cleared when it is clicked but `IMask` is throwing a warning:

> Element value has changed outside the mask. Sync the mask using mask.updateValue() for it to work correctly.

I've tried to use all of the ways I could find to update the value, such as `mask.updateValue()` though I still see the error.

```
import IMask from "imask";
import {contador} from "./lib/contador";
import {NewGame} from "./lib/novoJogo";
import {SorteioNumero} from "./lib/sorteioDoNumero";

let input = document.querySelector("#number");
const mask = IMask(input, {
  mask: Number,
  min: 0,
  max: 10,
});

input.addEventListener("click", () => {
  input.value = "";
  mask.updateValue();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

In your case, you should just write it like this:

```
input.addEventListener("click", () => {
  mask.updateValue("");
});
```

instead of

```
input.addEventListener("click", () => {
  input.value = "";
  mask.updateValue();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing the warning regarding the value being out of sync because you are updating the input field's value directly on the DOM element rather than using the `IMask` object, this updates the input field however `IMask` cannot see this change.

The correct way to update the value of an `IMask` input is to directly update the value of the `.value` property of the `IMask` object you created:

```js
import IMask from "imask";
import {contador} from "./lib/contador";
import {NewGame} from "./lib/novoJogo";
import {SorteioNumero} from "./lib/sorteioDoNumero";

let input = document.querySelector("#number"); // This is your raw DOM element.

const mask = IMask(input, { // This is your IMask object.
  mask: Number,
  min: 0,
  max: 10,
});

input.addEventListener("click", () => {
    mask.value = ""; // Clear IMask object value.
});
```

See *'Get/set value and unmasked value'* here: https://imask.js.org/guide.html#masked-base